# Forcing dimensions on a content editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could one force a content editable div to behave like a text box? That is, it has a fixed horizontal width but expands infinitely vertically? Here's a jsfiddle, and below is a copy of the code in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seoj7cgq/

```
<!--How do I force the text to stay in the div horizontally and scroll infinitely vertically?-->
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>

  .element {
    max-height: 200px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="element" contenteditable=true>
    this is the text
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`overflow-x`](http://devdocs.io/css/overflow-x) and [`overflow-y`](http://devdocs.io/css/overflow-y) properties:

```css
.element {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #999;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" contenteditable=true>this is the text</div>
```